# While overriding a button's default style using a resource, click event is not triggered

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game in WPF and using buttons in a 3X3 grid for the same. I want to override the default button style, for example, while hovering over the button, the background color shouldn't change. But after creating a static resource, the button click event isn't getting triggered anymore. Here's my code :

Button (this button doesn't trigger the click event):

```
<Button Name="Button1X1" Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="" BorderThickness="0, 0, 2.5, 2.5" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Button (this button triggers the click event):

```
<Button Name="Button1X2" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content=""  Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TicTacToeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Also, the border thickness property set in Button1X1 is not reflected.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want an invisible button that is always invisible? Do you want it to be visible when the mouse is not over it? The template is what creates the visual elements of the button. Right now, it is creating nothing. When you replace the template, you have replaced the thing that shows a border. You must replace it *with* something.

Comment: I want it to be an invisible button always, even on mouse hover.

Comment: When you say you want it to be invisible, do you mean you still want to see a border around it?

Comment: Because there are no visual elements inside the control template. Use [`Style.Triggers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. See examples.

Comment: If you want buttons with nothing inside use `Border` as the `ControlTemplate` root with the `Background` property set to `Transparent`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes and it should be dependant on the position of a button in the 3X3 grid. For the center-most button(i.e at position 2X2), it should have borders on all four sides. Whereas for 1X1 only the right and bottom border should be visible. Is that possible?

Comment: @YohDeadfall yes that works perfectly. I still have the border thickness problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual elements of the Button control are created by its template. You replaced the template with a template which doesn't create anything, so there's nothing to click on.

If you want the button always to be transparent, you don't need the trigger to set it that way on mouse over. The style below will create a clickable button which by default has no visible UI -- but it's still there, so you can still click on it.

```
<Style x:Key="TicTacToeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    >
                    <ContentPresenter
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's a quick example of a Tic-Tac-Toe board. I used UniformGrid instead of regular Grid to simplify the XAML. You may want to change the height and width of the grid. Note I just altered the style above so it has a BorderBrush that isn't transparent.

I didn't add click handlers. You already know how to add those.

A much more sophisticated approach to this would be an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate, but this will get you going for now.

```
<UniformGrid
    Width="300"
    Height="300"
    Rows="3"
    Columns="3"
    >
    <!-- BorderThickness is comma-separated values for Left,Top,Right,Bottom -->
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button1X1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button1X2" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button1X3" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" />

    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button2X1" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button2X2" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button2X3" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" />

    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button3X1" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button3X2" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TicTacToeButtonStyle}" Name="Button3X3" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks :) The click event works perfectly now. Also on mouse hover, the button remains invisible. But the border thickness property isn't set.

Comment: Yes it works like a charm. I realised where I was going wrong. Thanks :)